# Loan Pattern / Automatic Resource Management in Java

Tags: c#, java

I have tried to implement automatic resource management for Java (something like C#'s `using`). Following is the code I have come up with:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.io.*;

interface ResourceUser<T> {
  void use(T resource);
}

class LoanPattern {
  public static <T> void using(T resource, ResourceUser<T> user) {
    Method closeMethod = null;
    try {
      closeMethod = resource.getClass().getMethod("close");
      user.use(resource);
    }
    catch(Exception x) {
      x.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      try {
        closeMethod.invoke(resource);
      }
      catch(Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    using(new PrintWriter(System.out,true), new ResourceUser<PrintWriter>() {
      public void use(PrintWriter writer) {
        writer.println("Hello");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Please analyze the above code and let me know of any possible flaws and also suggest how I can improve this. Thank you.

(Sorry for my poor English. I am not a native English speaker.)

Comment: One issue I'd say is that your ResourceUser's method can't return a value. You'd probably want that in many cases. That should be easy though.

Answer (score 2):

I would modify your `using` method like:

```
public static <T> void using(T resource, ResourceUser<T> user) {
    try {
        user.use(resource);
    } finally {
        try {
            Method closeMethod = resource.getClass().getMethod("close");
            closeMethod.invoke(resource);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // not closable
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // not closable
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you need to define the behavior you want for the case that the resource is not *closable* (when you catch the above exceptions). You can either throw a specific exception like `UnclosableResourceException` or completely ignore this case. You can even implement 2 methods with these 2 behaviors (`using` and `tryUsing`).

Comment: I don't see how ignoring would ever be a valid choice. Passing something to that method that didn't define a close method would be a programming error, and would lead to errors going unnoticed if you thought something was being closed but it wan't. Not to mention the cost of the exception that would be created each time.